# A Missing Data Issue in Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I'm having a missing data problem in Google Places API! As seen in the example below, the Google Place additional info like mobile number, alternate phone, fax phone, are shown in the Google Map search results, but not through the Google Places API!

Following this link, you could notice the added alternate phone number, 
mobile:

www.google.com/maps/place?cid=4256683212236351718&q=hamza+kamaleddine+home&hl=en&ved=0CBQQ-gswAA&sa=X&ei=cO4wT4arE8Wp8QOZqITuDA

But using the Google Places API (using the HTTP request below), I am retrieving the following Json object:

The Place Search Request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.8113420,35.619370&radius=500&name=hamza&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBmT2NaNDJqSmZceuXD-pUrtDyHsC8kcz4

The Place Details Request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CnRvAAAAbkRqsybX6Gvpr-nqkIYi1QJKegY900fj6dSPzPUST9RJBX_YZ9wlY3_sY27J1u31Et42bQVYgkTzR9FNW9PwhdfXOcWBE7J8AWFGNAX0CRK-WVh0bsReKMcNjKUHQ7nTvgrq9PUKJrQdJWNHSyQgHxIQe_tRjNX5NPBcbdN03NjgPBoUOGcFXglRkNVmm73z8WpFOErLT1s&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBmT2NaNDJqSmZceuXD-pUrtDyHsC8kcz4

The Place Details Response (JSON):

```
{ 
   "html_attributions" : [], 
   "result" : { 
      "address_components" : [ 
         { 
            "long_name" : "Aley", 
            "short_name" : "Aley", 
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ] 
         }, 
         { 
            "long_name" : "LB", 
            "short_name" : "LB", 
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ] 
         }, 
         { 
            "long_name" : "1000", 
            "short_name" : "1000", 
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ] 
         } 
      ], 
      "formatted_address" : "Ain Al Jdide Road, طريق عين الجديدة, Aley, Lebanon", 
      "formatted_phone_number" : "70 975 590", 
      "geometry" : { 
         "location" : { 
            "lat" : 33.8113420, 
            "lng" : 35.619370 
         } 
      }, 
      "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png", 
      "id" : "a1063b63d187a576cf420e459aca9141e46bb8b6", 
      "international_phone_number" : "+961 70 975 590", 
      "name" : "Hamza Kamaleddine - Home", 
      "reference" : "...", 
      "types" : [ "establishment" ], 
      "url" : "http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=4256683212236351718", 
      "vicinity" : "Ain Al Jdide Road, طريق عين الجديدة, Aley", 
      "website" : "http://lb.linkedin.com/in/hkamaleddine" 
   }, 
   "status" : "OK" 

}
```

As you can notice, the mobile number, alternate, and fax numbers are missing!

How to solve this issue please?

Much Thanks!

Comment: I am having a similar problem, but in this case the suburb and city are missing for particular addresses. Surely that should be supported by the places API? Most addresses do report sublocality and locality. I raised an issue for it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179203679

Answer (score 0):

The Google Places API does not currently support this feature.

There is a feature request for this in the Places API issue tracker here: 
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3905

Please click the 'star' icon to be notified of future changes, and to let us know you are interested in seeing it resolved.

Cheers

Chris