# How to add more than one phone number in the "Main Phone" field of Google Places' bulk file?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

When adding more than one phone number in the "Main Phone" field of Google Places' uploaded bulk file, I'm having the formatted phone number validation message. I don't want to add the alternative phone under the "Alternative Phone" field because this field is not retrieved through the Google Places API!

The link to the missing data problem is found at:
[A Missing Data Issue in Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325262/a-missing-data-issue-in-google-places-api)

So is there a way to upload the bulk file having more than 1 pone number under the "Main Phone" attribute??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add more than one phone number in "Main Phone" field as this is not supported by Google Places. You must conform to the formatting rules when uploading bulk places as specified here: http://support.google.com/places/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1722104

As the formatting guide states: "Phone numbers must be valid in the country where your listing is located.", adding more than one number into the "Main Phone" field is not classified as a valid listing.

Your only option is to use just one phone number as returned by the Google Places API or wait until the feature request for the Google Places API to return more than one phone number has been filled: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3905

For anyone else interested in seeing this feature added to the Google Places API please click the 'star' icon to be notified of future changes, and to let us know you are interested in seeing it resolved.